# Sitecore Commerce installation fails in Docker

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation, docker, container

Using - `Sitecore.Commerce.Container.SDK.2.0.159`

We were able to successfully install `Sitecore XP 10.1` in `docker` on our local machine running on `Windows 10 64-bit`.
However, when we tried to install `Sitecore Commerce 10.1` in the `docker`, the installation fails.

There is a `"solr-init"` error in the process.

```
ERROR: for solr-init  manifest for scr.sitecore.com/sxc/sitecore-xc0-solr-init:10.1-ltsc2019 not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by "10.1-ltsc2019" is not found
ERROR: manifest for scr.sitecore.com/sxc/sitecore-xc0-solr-init:10.1-ltsc2019 not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by "10.1-ltsc2019" is not found
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the error message as text, not an image. Google will never find this.

Comment: @MarkCassidy great point! I added the text version of the error in the image. Thank you for bringing it up.

Answer (score 3):

Checking the official [Sitecore images tags list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/docker-images/master/tags/sitecore-tags.md), it seems that the `sitecore-xc0-solr-init` image is missing. You should open a ticket with Sitecore Support to let them know that it is missing.

In the meantime, you can update the image name of the `solr-init` service in your `docker-compose.yml` file to use the existing `sitecore-xc1-solr-init` image instead (xc1 instead of xc0) or use the [container deployment specs for XC1](https://github.com/Sitecore/container-deployment/tree/master/sxc/10.1/xc1). The scaling of the XC topology should not have any impact on the Solr initialization job.